# Image of closed sets in pseudometric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Stephen Willard's book on general topology describes pseudometric space as follows:

Tuple $(M, \rho)$ of set $M$ and function $\rho : M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $\rho(x, y) \ge 0$ for all $x, y \in M$
2. $\rho(x, x) = 0$ for all $x \in M$
3. $\rho(x, y) = d(y, x)$ for all $x, y \in M$
4. $\rho(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ for all $x, y, z \in M$

And there are exercises:

1. Let $(M, \rho)$ be pseudometric space. Define a relation $\sim$ on $M$ by $x \sim y$ iff $\rho(x, y) = 0$. Then $\sim$ is equivalence relation.
2. If $M^*$ is the set of equivalence classes in $M$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$ and if $\rho^*$ is defined on $M^*$ by $\rho^*([x], [y]) = \rho(x, y)$, then $\rho^*$ is a well-defined metric on $M^*$.
3. If $h: M \to M^*$ is the mapping $h(x) = [x]$, then set $A$ in $M$ is closed(open) iff $h(A)$ is closed(open) in $M^*$.

I solved first two exercises. But I found a counterexample in the third exercise. That is here:

Let $M = \lbrace a, b, c \rbrace$ and $\rho(a, a) = \rho(b, b) = \rho(c, c) = \rho(b, c) = \rho(c, b) = 0$ and $\rho(a, b) = \rho(b, a) = \rho(a, c) = \rho(c, a) = 1$ and $A = \lbrace a, b \rbrace$. Then there is no $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $U(c, \epsilon) \subset A^c$. ($U(c, \epsilon)$ is $\epsilon$-disk.) So $A$ is not closed. But since $b \sim c$, $[c] \in h(A)$. So $h(A) = \lbrace [a], [b] \rbrace = M^*$ and is closed.

Is there ane error in the exercise or my proof?

Comment: Your reasoning looks correct to me (you may also consider a simple example: two points with zero distance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(c)$ part *should* say: if $A$ is open in $M$ then $h[A]$ is open in $M^\ast$ and also for closed. There was another question about it recently. So the "iff" in the question is indeed a mistake (it's an old book..)